# Is duplicating content from other websites onto your own website good or bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, web-development, template

I built a website by copying content from other sites.

Is that OK from an SEO perspective?

Answer (score 2):

You will get slammed. I checked the site you linked. It appears to be boiler plate RSS feed stuff which Google will de-list and at least never rank.

We get these questions all the time.

The answer is this.

Duplicate content without attribution will get a site in serious trouble. Both sites.

If you are copying content without permission, then you will be violating copyright laws and can be sued and possibly charged of a crime. Most countries have copyright laws and respect other countries copyright laws and will help to prosecute and enable collections from any law suit.

A DMCA complaint may be filed against you. One complaint can be filed for each and every piece of copied content if you do not have permission. Enough complaints from even a single source will cause you trouble not only for this site, but others in the future.

As well, sites that do have permission and use RSS feeds and similar methods of obtaining content will never rank. This is even more true if the content is spun content.

Do not do this.

Websites are real work. Nothing is free in this world. If you want to have a website and make money, then you have to do it the way everyone else does. With real work and imagination.